# looping with if and for but not getting expected output

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script as below, which runs and giving me output as below.

Output:

```
4
3
```

But my expected output is as below. Can someone point me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
1
2
3
4
```

```
#!/bin/bash

region=('eu-central-1' 'us-east-1')
envs=('prod' 'stage')

for regions in "${region[@]}"; do

for env in "${envs[@]}"; do

if [ "${regions[*]}" == "eu-central" ] && [[ "${env[*]}" == "stage" ]]; then

echo 1

elif [ "${regions[*]}" == "eu-central" ] && [[ "${env[*]}" == "prod" ]]; then

echo 2

elif [ "${regions[*]}" == "us-east-1" ] && [[ "${env[*]}" == "stage" ]]; then

echo 3

elif [ "${regions[*]}" == "us-east-1" ] && [[ "${env[*]}" == "prod" ]]; then

echo 4

fi
done
done
```

Comment: Be consistent with your variable names, particularly the pluralization: `envs` is an array and `env` is one element; but `region` is an array, but `regions` is one element -- the array should be plural and the element should be singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're comparing against `eu-central` but the array includes `eu-central-1`
2. You're not using the loop variables, instead off `"${regions[*]}"`
   just use `"$regions"`
3. Proper indent your script

---

Applying the above gives us:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for regions in "${region[@]}"; do
    for env in "${envs[@]}"; do
        if [ "$regions" == "eu-central-1" ] && [[ "${env[*]}" == "stage" ]]; then
            echo 1
        elif [ "$regions" == "eu-central-1" ] && [[ "$env" == "prod" ]]; then
            echo 2
        elif [ "$regions" == "us-east-1" ] && [[ "$env" == "stage" ]]; then
            echo 3
        elif [ "$regions" == "us-east-1" ] && [[ "$env" == "prod" ]]; then
            echo 4
        fi
    done
done
```

---

```
2
1
4
3
```

---

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVDLCsIwELznK9YoVoVSqt5Kwf8IPfSxbQMlkaT1In573bSlKIhF3EPY3ZnMTJKltu779SrIpAoyGhgzWEmt4p2HnZ@jak3a@KEHXmd9TG1L/Z6hulliXI0uCLFtWiFtWakNjNctSAV8cx8ncUkePIJCM6ByLBKYGE7qHXclSxCETmIc4hj4ax4OCWy3IMQkIQ6kMLCGMAQnEbQ1qlnRFea1hnBeYfOLDbmMBPfqbwbHBYP5Iz@qL@Y//SW/FP48r0o5tIVWyNzR908)